# directions (path find) given kml supplied bounds

Tags: kml, google, google-maps-api

Im trying to generate directions using google.maps.DirectionsService
and I really need those directions bounded by the paths defined from
within a pre-made kml file. I have reviewed the API docs for google maps and doesnt seem they have this functionality.

This is for a custom app where areas are
already defined inside a kml file that is layered over google maps.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: After looking around, this is the only approach I have.

Use Cases:

1.- If start point is outside the KML bounded paths

  1.1 - Get directions from start point to nearest entrance to KML bounded path
        using google.maps.DirectionsService

  1.2 - If Destination point is outside KML bounded path

      1.2.1 - Get directions to nearest entrance of KML bounded path from destination using google.maps.DirectionsService

      1.2.2 - From the nearest entrance used as an end point in 1.1, find shortest path through KML bounded path using Dijkstra's algorithm to entrance found in 1.2.1.